# Many to One Relation in Django With Existing Objects

Tags: python, django, many-to-one

I've started to study Django yesterday and I'm having some trouble with to creating a **Many to One Relation** based on objects I've previously created.

## models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', 'code')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    code =  models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='/img/products')
    items = models.ForeignKey('Item')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', 'code')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

## admin.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib import admin
from Cadastro.models import Item, Product

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Item
    list_display = ['code', 'name']
    list_filter = []
    search_fields = ['name', 'code']
    save_on_top = True


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Product
    list_display = ['name', 'price']
    list_filter = []
    search_fields = ['name']
    save_on_top = True

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

## Problem:

My problem is here:

```
items = models.ForeignKey('Item')
```

I want to create various **Item** objects, first.

After that, when I'll create the **Products**, I want to see a list of all my **Items** and select many items to be part of a **Product**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relationship is going the wrong way. If a `Product` can have multiple `Item`s, make a `ForeignKey` from `Item` to `Product`. With the `ForeignKey` on `Product`, you're saying each product has exactly one `Item`, but each `Item` can belong to multiple `Product`s.

The docs have more details and examples:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: In this case, When I create an Item, I'll instantiate it in one Product.
I'm asking about the possibility of a Product have a **list** of Items. But this items are already instantiated.

Comment: Foreign keys on the `many` side are the standard way to represent `ManyToOne` relationships in relational databases. Django will give you an automatic reverse of the relationship, unless you tell it not to - look at the `article_set` examples in the docs. The `Reporter` model doesn't need an explicit field to look up `Article`s belonging to each reporter. In your case, you'd probably have `item_set` as an automatic field on `Product`.